# fork writes filehandle again

Tags: c, file, fork, printf

My code looks somehow like this:

```
//INCLUDES

FILE *file;

void handlesocket(int socket);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    openlog("daemon", LOG_PID, LOG_USER);
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "daemon started.");
    file = fopen("/var/log/daemon.log","a+");
    fprintf(file,"Opened log file...");

     while (1) {
         pid = fork();
         if (pid == 0)  {
             handlesocket(socket);
             exit(0);
         }
         else close(socket);
     }
}

void handlesocket(int socket)
{
//handle socket
}
```

Basically, it is waiting for a new connections and then forks itself. (I removed all the socket code so it's easier to read.

My problem is that everytime a new connection comes in (and a new fork() is getting called) the `fprintf` seems to get called again and there is a new `"Opened log file..."` in my log.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fork duplicates the process completely - including the buffers used by fprintf. You need to flush the file handle right before the fork so that your forked process starts with io buffers clear:

```
fprintf( file, "opening log file\n" );
fflush( file );
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! But shouldn't the buffers be cleared after fprintf() is done?

Comment: Sometimes yes sometimes no. I believe stderr will auto-flush after every newline. But most streams will not.

Comment: (which is a good thing, since most of the time you want buffering since it improves performance by reducing the number of system calls needed)

Comment: While searching for a solution i stumbled upon this: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/POS38-C.+Beware+of+race+conditions+when+using+fork+and+file+descriptors
Does this also apply to writing to files?

Comment: Yes. It is less of an issue than reading from a duplicate file handle. But sure - the output from each process may be interleaved in the file in an unpredictable manner.

Comment: So to be safe i should reopen the filehandle after forking?

Comment: Of both threads are going to write to the same log file you will still have the interleaving problem. If you don't mind interleaving I believe it is safe for both threads to write to the same file handle.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista could you explain this a little bit more? 
"The interleaving problem"?

Comment: First @R is right - I meant processes, but I think the same applies to threads. Two threads or processes writing to the same file handle may have their output interleaved. That is 2 threads writing "hello world" *may* result in "hehellollo  wwoorldrld" or something like that in the file.

Comment: And by having separate filehandles you can prevent this? There still could be 2 processes writing at the same time.